# Redirect URLs from the old domain that ends with trailing slash to the new domain without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, url-rewriting

I'd like to reduce the redirect chains currently I'm dealing with by directly redirecting the URLs from the old domain that ends with a trailing slash to the new domain without a trailing slash.

My current setup does like this:

olddomain.com/page redirects to newdomain.com/page (this is OK)

However, if the user enters olddomain.com/page/ it first redirects to newdomain.com/page/ and then to newdomain.com/page

What I want is to directly redirect olddomain.com/page/ to newdomain.com/page

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So make your pattern allow for an optional trailing slash then, but without capturing it. `(.*)/?$`

Comment: @CBroe That regex would _capture_ the "optional" trailing slash since the _greedy_ `*` quantifier would consume it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
> ```

If the source URLs may or may not contain a trailing slash, but always redirect to the URL *without* a trailing slash then make the trailing slash optional in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, but *importantly* you need to make the `*` quantifier non-greedy so it does not consume the trailing slash (since the greedy `*` quantifier will take priority over the optional token that follows).

For example:

```
 RewriteRule (.*?)/?$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `*?` quantifier makes it non-greedy, so it consumes as *least* as possible.

The `NC` flag is redundant here since the pattern `(.*?)/?$` is effectively case-insensitive anyway.

Comment: Wow, thank you MrWhite I have been searching for this for quite a long time yet no one has come up with a solution that actually works. Yours did the trick so thank you very much, you saved my day!